# Интервал слайдера WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как задать слайдеру интервал например от 10 до 20.
Когда слайдер будет в самой левой части, то значение будет 10.
И оочень буду благодарен если вы подскажете код который при сдвиге слайдера будет показывать сверху значения

Comment: Так же мне нужно значение слайдера указанный пользователем присвоить переменной.Заранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да запросто!

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=sl, StringFormat=F2}"/>
    <Slider Name="sl" Minimum="10" Maximum="20" Value="{Binding Var}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

даёт такой слайдер:

[image: картинки!]

Свойство (а не поле!), в котором будет значение, должно лежать в `DataContext` и называться `Var`. Ну или по-другому, тогда вам придётся подправить привязку.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Kamil: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @Kamil если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ на ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый, поставив зелёную галочку (слева от ответа) [help/accepted-answer]